# Change default bold series for teletype only

Tags: fonts, bold, font-encodings

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}       %% see below
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   %%

\begin{document}

Hello \textbf{World \texttt{of} Code!}
%%                  ^^^^^^^^^^^

\end{document}
```

Without the packages, the bold font would use series `b`. However, with the two packages above, the bold series becomes `bx`. Unfortunately, lmodern teletype doesn't have such a series, resulting in the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/lmtt/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmtt/b/n' tried instead on input line 8.
```

So what I'd like to do is change the default bold series *for the teletype font only* from `bx` to `b`.

How can I do this?

Comment: The usual default is bx not b, so that is not changed by the packages. The substitution is already using the "silent"  substitution `ssub` rather than `sub` (so it does not warn on the terminal, only the log) so basically the behaviour you describe is as designed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: So you don't mind having the log file littered with substitution warnings like that?

Comment: The log from your test file has 140 lines, so those two don't worry me no, they are more informative than many of the others!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is as designed but if you want to lose all (log-only) font warnings then:

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\def\@font@info#1{}
\makeatother


\usepackage{lmodern}       %% see below
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   %%

\begin{document}

Hello \textbf{World \texttt{of} Code!}
%%                  ^^^^^^^^^^^

\end{document}
```

has 66 rather than 140 lines in the log.

Comment: Something tells me that this isn't changing the font mappings at all :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB you do not want to change the font mappings. latex is already doing exactly what you ask. detecting tt and in that case using b rather than bx for bold. The only thing that you want differently is that you don't want to be told that it is happening.